# How do I parse these kind of xml data?

Tags: android, xml-parsing

The data I need to parse somehow looks like these:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<parent>

<child ID="1" Name="CHILD" Order="1">

<subchild ID="1" Name="SUB_CHILD" Order="1">
<subchild ID="1" Name="SUB_CHILD_NODE1" Order="01"/>
<subchild ID="2" Name="SUB_CHILD_NODE2" Order="02"/>
</subchild>

</child>

</parent>
```

This is like opening sub-folders, main folder -> inside_main_folder -> data inside inside_main_folder. Sorry I can't explain it, this is the first time seeing this kind of data.

I had parsed data before but it looks like this:

```
<results>
    <result>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>Mark</name>
        <score>6958</score>
    </result>
    <result>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>Wesley</name>
        <score>4039</score>
    </result>
</result>
```

I'm using DOMParser by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those "ID", "Name" and "Order" are attributes of node. When you get a node, use getAttribute method (check DOM document to see what exact name of the method is) on the node to parse value of "ID", "Name" and "Order".

Comment: I got it! Thank you!

`NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("CATEGORY");

  Element element = (Element) nodeList.item(0);
  String name = element.getAttribute("Name");
  String id = element.getAttribute("ID");

  Toast.makeText(this, "" + name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

  HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
  
  map.put("id", id);
  map.put("name", name);  
  mylist.add(map);`